# Parse string as tuple or enum or dictionary

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I have this data coming into my cloud function:

```
let geison=`{
"message" : [{"something":1}, {"is":2} ,{"up":3}, {"today":4}]
}`
```

I'm trying to access the keys and values of each item. At first, I parse it like so:

```
const body = JSON.parse(geison);
```

And I can see each individual list item, if I iterate:

```
body.message.forEach((item: { type: string; }) => {
      console.log(item.type) //this prints out "undefined"
      console.log(item) //this prints out the item, curly brackets and all
});
```

How do I parse the list item in order to access its key and value separately?

Comment: What are you trying to do with these keys/values? Can you share an example of the output you're trying to get?

Comment: I'm trying to call them separately and print them to console. For each one, I want two variables. For example, in the case of the first, I want a string variable with value "something" and a number variable with value 1.

Comment: None of those objects has a property named type.

Comment: That's fine, @jonrsharpe, I just added that line cause I thought it showed the type of the object. But it's not really what my question is about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objects will always have only one key and value, you could do something like this:

```
body.message.forEach((item: { [k: string]: number }) => {
  console.log(Object.keys(item)[0]);
  console.log(Object.values(item)[0]);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, human!

Answer (score 1):

Your object types like `{something: 1}` is not a `{type: string}`, since the former has no key named `type` property and no value of a `string` type.  So when you iterate through the `message` array, you try to get the `type` property, which is `undefined`.  And the whole item is an object, so you get the curly braces.  You've misclassified the type of the objects in the array.  `JSON.parse()` produces a value of the very permissive  [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) type, so this misclassification only bites you at runtime.

So, the correct description of your object type would be one with a single, *dynamically* keyed property whose value is of type `number` (at least for the example you gave).  Such an object structure with a *single* unknown key isn't easily supported in TypeScript.

You could instead use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) like `{[k: string]: number}`, which means "an object type with some dynamic `string` keys whose values are `number`s".  This is probably close enough to what you have, but it differs in the number of unspecified keys.  An index signature can have any number, whereas you only have one.  Let's just move forward and then take care only to grab the first (and only) key.

I'd use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler what to expect the parsed json to look like:

```
const body = JSON.parse(geison) as { message: Array<{ [k: string]: number }> };
```

Then, for each item in the `message` array (which is know known to the compiler to be an array of dictionaries-of-numbers), get its (assumed single) key by taking the first element of the output of [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
body.message.forEach(item => {
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  console.log(key);
  console.log(item[key]);
});
```

This should give you the behavior you expect.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/DYUwLgBA5iCWDOB7AdhAvBABgbwLACgAiAWxHngEMZCIAuCAbW0KVLAAtZkpDaBGAL4AaCMwS8ATAIhDmAVwAOvAMzDRhMIgAmFAJ68ALAIC6BAZgIQCAYxTxIAI2270EAFIBlAPIA5AHQKFABO8CAAFDAIKACUEBTwohCk5FQg9ACCQUF6ADzYjADW9PZBXFDG9MhyxA4gQRACAHwNANwEBE5aun7JlDB+AGaIQQCiFNbsYbBgIMTozXj4EBC2yPYQBSAuGF4OAFYg1mB+m7rwUzPE0QwADMZtSyt2iKB+wIhQYafRD8urSK93p9prMGKdjD8zD8IEA)